# Resource request: superposition of triangular lattice and its hexagonal dual lattice

Tags: reference-request

I was wondering if anyone knew of a source for pdfs of graph paper with both the triangular lattice and its dual hexgonal lattice superimposed over each other?

I would like this to hand out to my students and have them draw subgraphs (and their duals), but am having trouble finding or generating this.

Comment: The AMS has an image (gif) in line with what you are asking about [**here**](http://www.ams.org/featurecolumn/images/august2008/triangular.dual.gif). And so, while it is not an ideal solution, there is at least a temporary fix possible by pasting together this image ([**e.g.**](http://i.imgur.com/YDwXy7N.jpg)).

Comment: Because you've included generating in your question, you might be interested in this thread on Stackoverflow which includes a variety of programming solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005042/language-or-package-for-drawing-geometric-diagrams